# Why am I obtaining this error trying to install programs via apt-get? Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

Tags: command-line, apt, software-installation

I am not so into Linux. On an Ubuntu VM on a client environment it seems that I can't use **apt-get** command.

In particular trying to perform:

```
sudo apt-get install ntpdate
```

I am obtain this message error:

> Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

Here a screenshot:

[image]

What could be the cause of the error? Can something block apt-get on this infrastructure? (firewall or something like this?)

Altro trying to perform a:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I have the same problem

I tried also to install other application via apt-get and I am facing the same issue? In case there are other solution to manually download and install **ntpdate** without using apt-get?

Comment: Is this your only network-related problem? All other network access works properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `sudo apt update && sudo apt install ntpdate` to update the list of available installs first before trying to get [ntpdate](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/ntpdate.8.html).

If that fails, you could have a problem connecting to the **archive.ubuntu.com** server, which normally resolves itself soon.

Comment: and what can be the cause?

Comment: Firstly, did `sudo apt update && sudo apt install ntpdate` solve the problem?